# Laravel Raw DB Insert Affected Rows

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, laravel-4

**I'm using raw queries with laravel 4**, **is there a way to check affected rows on an insert?** `DB::getPdo()->rowCount();` gives me an `"undefined method" error`. Code is as follows:

```
$query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO table (id) VALUES (?)";
$doQuery = DB::insert($query, array($value));
if ($doQuery) {
    return DB::getPdo()->last();
} else {
    return 0;
}
```

If not, is there an easy way to figure out whether an insert was done or not without making it two queries?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this function:

> *int **affectingStatement**(string $query, array $bindings = array())*
>
> Run an SQL statement and get the number of rows affected.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> - string  $query
> - array   $bindings
>
> **Return Value**
>
> - int

This function is already documented for laravel 4.2 as well as for 5.4. *[Edit note: The documentation for those versions are removed from the laravel site.]*

Note that `insert()` is an alias for `statement()` and will return a boolean. While the functions `update()` and `delete()` are aliases for `affectingStatement()`. So if you want to be funny and confuse the reviewers you could also write `$rowCount = DB::delete("INSERT IGNORE ...", $bindings)` - and it will work.

Comment: 5.4 link is broken aswell - I removed both. 8.x API can be found [here](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Connection.html#method_affectingStatement).

Answer (score 3):

Well I figured out a workaround that should be just as efficient - use INSERT INTO instead of INSERT IGNORE INTO and use try/catch.

```
   $query = "INSERT INTO table (id) VALUES (?)";
    try {
        DB::insert($query, array($value));
        return 1;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Nice solution, looking forward to see if there are developments on this