# Count number of rows inserted using Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Im currently running Laravel 5.8. I've configured a few Oracle databases in my project whereby we're required to sometimes run some SQL update/insert statements against oracle databases. These are input via a GUI and submitted into the backend which is validated and then run. I'm using yajra/oci8 package to plugin to these databases and using raw SQL queries for the update/insert statements. To execute the SQL, i use this:

````
$rowsUpdated = DB::connection($database)->$sqlType($sql);```

$database = the database connection to run the SQL against

$sqlType  = this is insert/update depending on the input

$sql      = this is the raw SQL update/insert statement to run
````

When i run the update statements, `$rowsUpdated` correctly shows the number of rows that were affected. However when i run the following insert statement, it only returns a value of 1 every time. For example, the insert statement below inserts 2 rows, but the return value is only 1:

```
INSERT ALL
 into schema.table (ORDER_ID, PRODUCT_TYPE, created_dtm, ORDER_TYPE, ORDER_STATUS, CANCELLING_STATE, last_modified_dtm, OPERATOR_CODE)
 values (10000006, 'FTTC', sysdate - 1024, 'Provide', 'Completed', null, sysdate - 1020, 'test')
 into schema.table (ORDER_ID, PRODUCT_TYPE, created_dtm, ORDER_TYPE, ORDER_STATUS, CANCELLING_STATE, last_modified_dtm, OPERATOR_CODE)
 values (10000007, 'FTTC', sysdate - 1024, 'Provide', 'Completed', null, sysdate - 1020, 'test')
SELECT * FROM DUAL;
```

How can I get a count of the number of rows inserted?

Edit: Thanks for providing the answer.
[Laravel Raw DB Insert Affected Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31466584/laravel-raw-db-insert-affected-rows)

Comment: I think when it returns 1 it is returning "true", meaning that it was successful btw :)

Comment: `$insertedRowsNum=0;
$rowsNumBeforeInsert = ModelName::count();
$rowsNumAfterInsert = ModelName::count();
$insertedRowsNum=$rowsNumAfterInsert-$rowsNumBeforeInsert;`